# Moodle Paypal_enrolment plugin not working with Paypal Sandbox?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, moodle

I am using Moodle 1.9 Paypal_enrolment plugin so that to access the course student first pay the amount by paypal and then access the course.

I am following the steps given here:

http://docs.moodle.org/19/en/Paypal_enrolment

After implementing I want to test with Paypal Sanbox but facing some problem. How we can enable paypal sandbox so that I can test the flow in Paypal sandbox. Also check this link too http://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=171745 that elaborate similar problem as mine. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable the Paypal sandbox, you need to add the following line of code in `config.php`:

```
$CFG->usepaypalsandbox = 'TRUE';
```

Not sure if this has been fixed meanwhile, but you might also need to edit `ipn.php` to use SSL and port 443:

```
$paypaladdr = empty($CFG->usepaypalsandbox) ? 'www.paypal.com' : 'ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com';
$fp = fsockopen ($paypaladdr, 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
```

More information:

http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Enrolment_plugins#Note_about_Paypal_Sandbox

Comment: Thanks Roberto I will check the above mentioned option and will update here.